# Using A For Loop To Create Symbolic Variables

Tags: matlab, for-loop, symbolic-math

I am trying to create a large number of symbolic variables using a `for` loop, so that I do not have to type each individual variable. Here is my attempt:

```
for i 1:19
    yi = sym('yi');
end
```

However, I am getting this error: `Unexpected MATLAB expression.`

Comment: you need `=`, `for i=1:19`

Comment: Also the above script keeps creating the same symbolic variable. Maybe use `A = sym('A',dim)` if you want a vector symbolic value?

Comment: Originally I did that, but I did not find that helpful; the reason being that if I wanted to refer to y2, I would have to A(2), which would complicate things a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the Symbolic Math Toolbox but see if this helps:

```
for i=1:19
 eval(sprintf('y%d = sym(''y%d'')', i,i))
end
```

Although, I highly recommend against doing it this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`syms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) and a cell array to generate a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to do this:

```
varname = 'y';
idx = 19;
y = arrayfun(@(x)char(x),sym(varname,[1 idx]),'UniformOutput',false);
syms(y{:})
```

which creates nineteen distinct symbolic variables. No need for the explicit use of `eval`. If you want arbitrary numbering this is more flexible and probably faster:

```
varname = 'y';
idx = [1:3 9:12 17:19];
y = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf([varname '%d'],x),idx,'UniformOutput',false);
syms(y{:})
```

There are other ways to create the cell array of strings, e.g., using only `sprintf` and `textscan`, but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Here's another (simpler, but less elegant) option that uses the `symfun` creation capability of `syms`:

```
varname = 'y';
idx = 1:19;
y = sprintf([varname '%d,'],idx);
syms(['tmp(' y(1:end-1) ')']);
```

The symbolic function `tmp` can safely be cleared afterwards without bothering the other symbolic variables.